# ld makes all my functions link to the last one in header file

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, operating-system, ld

I've started working on a home-brew OS for learning purposes. So it works like this :

- Once the kernel is loaded I create a stack and call my kmain()
- In kmain I try calling function foo() defined in header.h

  ```
  //Header.h
  #ifndef INCLUDE_HEADER_H
  #define INCLUDE_HEADER_H

  int foo(char* buf);
  int bar();

  #endif
  ```

Using nm on my kernel I can clearly see that foo() is in the binary but when I disassemble kmain with gdb I see that foo isn't called, instead bar is.

This problem is recurrent on all headers containing multiple functions.

I compile on windows 10 in a Cygwin environment. I use the following arguments passed to nasm/gcc/ld in my makefile

```
    CC = gcc
    CFLAGS = -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc \
             -nostartfiles -fno-leading-underscore -nodefaultlibs\
             -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function\
             -c
    LD = i686-elf-ld
    LDFLAGS = -Tlink.ld -melf_i386
    AS = nasm
    ASFLAGS = -f elf
```

Any ideas why ?

EDIT :

```
   //screen.h
   #ifndef SCREEN_H
   #define SCREEN_H

   int test();
   void print(char c);

   #endif
```

And

```
  //kmain.c
  #include "screen.h"

  int kmain(){
      int b = test();
      print('A');
      return 0xcafebabe;
  }
```

nm kernel.elf

```
    $ nm kernel.elf
    e4524ffe a CHECKSUM
    00000000 a FLAGS
    0010011c b kernel_stack
    00004000 a KERNEL_STACK_SIZE
    00100000 T kmain
    001000c8 T loader
    001000dd t loader.loop
    1badb002 a MAGIC_NUMBER
    001000b0 T outb
    00100072 T print
    0010002c T strlen
    00100068 T test
    0010005c T testFunc
```

gdb disassembly of kmain:

```
    (gdb) disassemble kmain
    Dump of assembler code for function kmain:
    0x00100000 <kmain+0>:   push   %ebp
    0x00100001 <kmain+1>:   mov    %esp,%ebp
    0x00100003 <kmain+3>:   sub    $0x28,%esp
    0x00100006 <kmain+6>:   call   0x10006b <print+1> ;should call test but calls print instead
    0x0010000b <kmain+11>:  mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
    0x0010000e <kmain+14>:  movl   $0x41,(%esp) ;pushes 'A'
    0x00100015 <kmain+21>:  call   0x100084 <print+26> ;calls print('A')
    0x0010001a <kmain+26>:  mov    $0xcafebabe,%eax
    0x0010001f <kmain+31>:  leave
    0x00100020 <kmain+32>:  ret
    0x00100021 <kmain+33>:  nop
    0x00100022 <kmain+34>:  nop
    0x00100023 <kmain+35>:  nop
    End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: show us the disassembly.

Also remove all object files and recompile.

Comment: Oh I forgot those, I added them now.

Answer (score 0):

```
0x00100006 <kmain+6>:   call   0x10006b <print+1> ;should call test but calls print instead
```

`<print+1>` is just the label. This instruction does call the `test` function as can be seen from the address `0x10006b` :

```
00100068 T test
00100072 T print
```

It'll be clearer if you look at the disassembly of the compiled "screen.c".

Comment: Actually the call to 0x10006b lands in print anyway as I just checked with gdb. I used bochs debugger to step through the execution and I'm pretty sure test never gets called and print does (twice).

Comment: @NaoufelJamali : as I said in my answer, the `print` bit is just a label added as part of the disassembly - it doesn't necessarily correspond to the function name (especially not when you compiled with optimizations enabled, and debug symbols disabled). What counts is the actual code at the address `0x10006b`, and that's the code for the `test` function as indicated by the `nm` output.

Comment: nm says test is at 0x100068 not 0x10006b am I reading this wrong ?

Comment: @NaoufelJamali : it says it starts at that address. Look at the disassembly of the compiled "screen.c", and things will likely become more clear to you.

Comment: I've looked into that binary but I still don't get why my print function isn't getting called when I put it in a separate C file and works perfectly when I implement it right before kmain(). Here's the disassembly of screen.c [Pastebin screen.o](http://pastebin.com/8ezyuwRk)

Comment: @NaoufelJamali : you seem to be hung up on wanting the label in the disassembly to read `test` instead of `print` when calling the `test` function. I don't know what else to respond to that beyond what I've already said.

Comment: Umm I think I didn't make it clear : I don't actually want to label to be test, I don't care about that. I know it's a label and it doesn't mean anything code-wise. *My problem is that my function isn't called when I run the thing*.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was in the compiler tool-chain I was using. It's what created the weird linking problem. 
Here are the [instructions](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) I followed to compile a clean new Binutils + Gcc and it's working now !